# show custom popup on page refress and browser/tab close in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open popup when closing the tab or browser first time and get the user review. I used `onbeforeunload()`, but I need to handle page refresh and tab close deferent different event.

Comment: Have a look into modals in JS

Comment: provide a little of what you have found by yourself, maybe in a code-snippet example, what you are asking is a miniature framework.

Comment: please, open this link [https://makitweb.com/how-to-know-a-browser-tab-close-or-refresh-with-javascript/] and check demo [https://makitweb.com/demo/tabcloserefresh/] with **page refresh** and **browser tab close** both, I want custom popup at browser/tab close only not refresh because I need to add button and image in the popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You can't.

**Longer answer:** For rather obvious "security" reasons it is very limited what you can do when a user tries to navigate away from a page / close a tab or in any other way leave the site.

The reason is that browsers want to make absolutely sure that you cannot prevent the user from closing a tab or window that he / she wants to close.

Therefore the `onbeforeunload` javascript event - and by extension the `beforeunload` jQuery event - are extremely limited in what they can do. One of the things they definitely cannot do is prevent the page from closing - except using one very standardized and rather boring method the browser (usually) allows.